# Remove item from linked list in a good way

Tags: javascript, java, c, linked-list

in [this](https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux/transcript) TED talk Linus Torvalds showed "poor" and "good" programming tastes on example with removing item from linked list.

So the poor taste example:

[image]

And here goes the good taste:

[image]

Main point here is last if statement in bad taste example.

I am not a C/C++ developer and unfortunately for me i am thinking in "bad" taste.

My question here: is this possible to write "smart" solution without using if statement for special case on a programming language without C-style pointers ?
For example on java or javascript.

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Post the code itself.  You're going to get downvoted for that....

Comment: You can get help here to ask the better way your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments, but i think the question is clear here

Comment: I might've missed something, but it seems to me that the code doesn't redirect the previous entry to the one next to the removed entry.

Comment: @StackLloyd,  you are wrong as `entry` param is a valid reference to a member of the list. Either `entry->next` is pointing to **nothing** as it's the last element in the list or it is pointing to another valid member from that list.

Comment: @dbl Yes, but my question was about the element previous to the entry being removed. It still points to the deleted one, doesn't it?

Comment: Example 1: either `head = entry->next` (no prev element to point to head) or `prev->next = entry->next` (prev point to the element after next now). Example 2: `indirect` is actually a pointer to the `next` ref of the current element unless it's still pointing to the head...

Comment: It checks for `(*indirect) != entry` to run the loop, which means that `(*indirect) == entry` when it eventually finds it and does its job. Fine, alright, no problem. What about the previous element in the list, which pointed **TO** `entry`? Is its reference updated as well?

Comment: Your question will be closed. NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve] Your question is also opinion based and broad. In addition, the link to the talk is pointless as it may go dead over time so it adds nothing to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @WJS It's a direct violation of SO rules and a common error by new people who never took [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should read [mcve]

Comment: And you're not supposed to put code in comments either.  But I see folks with very high reps do it all the time and never get flagged.  The application of rules on this site are very inconsistent.

Comment: @WJS Yes. It's led to many of us getting frustrated and leaving SO in droves. But do not jump off the cliff just because others are doing so.

Comment: @Rob  Good point!

Comment: @StackLloyd it doesn't need to be updated. The code is directly substituting the value at the memory location. All references that pointed to `entry` still point at the same location, but the content at that location was replaced with `entry->next`.

Comment: @Arminius Thank you, I finally understood.

Comment: You can write a solution in Java that emulates this process.  Basically, you would need something like a `Pointer Node` that points to the `real node` which points to the `entry`.  But I wouldn't say it is worth doing.  That is a limitation of not being able to use `references` like C pointers.  On the other hand, I have never had a `segmentation violation`  or `bus error`in Java.

Comment: Thanks @WJS it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

regarding your question:

*is this possible to write "smart" solution without using if statement for special case on a programming language without C-style pointers*

The answer:

Almost anything is possible when writing code.

Answer (score 1):

I extended your code snippets to a whole .c-file to make it more understandable in the context:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}

typedef struct node nodde_t;

node_t* head;

/*bad code*/
void remove_list_entry_bad(node_t* entry){
    node_t* prev = NULL;
    node_t* walk = head;

    while(walk != entry){
        prev = walk;
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    if(!prev)
        head = entry->next;
    else
        prev->next = entry->next;
}

/*good code*/
void remove_list_entry_good(node_t* entry){
    
    node_t** indirect = &head;

    while ((*indirect) != entry)
        indirect = &(*indirect)->next;

    *indirect = entry->next;
}

int main(){

    node_t n1, n2, n3;
    
    n1.data = 45;
    n2.data = 8;
    n3.data = 32;

    head = &n1; 
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.next = NULL;
    
    remove_list_entry_good(&n2); /* instead : n1.next = &n3; */

    return 0;

}
```

I decided for Integers as the data, for simplicity.
The typedef thingy is for being able to write node_t instead of struct node. Yes, in C, you'd have to write the struct word every time you're using the type node. If your even unfamiliar with pointers, consider this code written in Java, with references instead of pointers:

```
package linked;
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
}
public class Test {
    Node head;

    /* bad code */
    void remove_list_entry_bad(Node entry) {
        Node prev = null;
        Node walk = head;

        while (walk != entry) {
            prev = walk;
            walk = walk.next;
        }

        if (prev == null)
            head = entry.next;
        else
            prev.next = entry.next;
    }

    /* good code */
    void remove_list_entry_good(Node entry) {
        Node indirect = head;

        //Node indirect = head;
        while (indirect.next != entry)
            indirect = indirect.next;

        indirect.next = entry.next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node n1, n2, n3;
        
        n1 = new Node();
        n2 = new Node();
        n3 = new Node();

        n1.data = 45;
        n2.data = 8;
        n3.data = 32;

        Test list = new Test();
        list.head = new Node();
        list.head.next = n1;
        n1.next = n2;
        n2.next = n3;
        n3.next = null;


        list.remove_list_entry_good(n1);

        Node walk = list.head.next;
        while (walk != null) {
            System.out.println("" + walk.data);
            walk = walk.next;
        }

    }
}
```

The Node class uses a recursive definition, like methods that call themselves over and over. If you wonder, why the Node class is written inside the MyList class, this is called a private class.

**Edit**
I have found something very interesting in C. The type of indirect must be node_t** with double stars. Don't know what that means, but it works.

**Edit**
I found something on the web that works and is simple at the same time! https://www.dineshonjava.com/delete-given-node-from-singly-linked-list/

```
void remove_list_entry_good(Node entry) {
    Node temp = entry.next; 
    entry.value = temp.value; 
    entry.next = temp.next; 
    temp = null; 
}
```

Comment: I think your `remove_list_entry_good` method will not work, as references in java passed by value, so if you change  `indirect = entry.next` reference it will not be changed on the original Node object